# Accessing Request.Url in controller initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here :

```
public baseController()
{
    string surl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

This is not accessible : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This one is OK :

```
public ActionResult index()
{
    string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

I believe current http context is only accessible on actionrendering ?
Ayway, I need to get this URL thing before actually calling an actionresult, I'm I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acces the url property by calling the current context directly

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```